# Linearity of the right inverse of a surjective linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Suppose we have a surjective linear map $f:V\to V$ on an infinite-dimensional vector space $V$. We know that every surjective map has at least one right inverse. So I was wondering... I know not all right inverses are linear, for example, on the space of real sequences
$$(a_0,a_1,a_2,\cdots)\mapsto(1,a_0,a_1,a_2,\cdots)$$
is a right inverse of the surjective linear map
$$(a_0,a_1,a_2,\cdots)\mapsto(a_1,a_2,\cdots)$$ but obviously isn't a linear map itself, but on the other hand $$(a_0,a_1,a_2,\cdots)\mapsto(0,a_0,a_1,a_2,\cdots)$$ is a linear right inverse.  So I was wondering... does there *always* exist a *linear* right inverse of any linear surjective map on an infinite-dimensional vector space over an arbitrary field $K$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you write $V=\ker f\oplus W $ (which can always be done), then the restriction  $f:W\to V $ is bijective, and you can use its inverse as your linear right-inverse.

Comment: Why can you always write V=ker f + W?

Comment: You take a basis $\{e_j\}$ of $\ker f$ and you extend it to a basis $\{e_j\}\cup\{f_k\}$ of $V$. Take $W=\operatorname{span}\{f_k:\ k\}$.

Comment: I think it's not true, but I don't know an example. In Brezis's book of functional analysis, Theorem 2.12 says the condition to have linear right inverse is that Ker f admits a complement. If it is always true, why would he impose this condition? Or it has to do with the continuity he asks for?

Comment: This question and answer have nothing to do with functional analysis. What you say is true when "complement" means "closed complement" and when talking about bounded operators.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Since you're assuming that surjective maps have a right inverse (which is equivalent to the axiom of choice), you know that every vector space has a basis.</sup>

Let $f\colon V\to W$ be a surjective linear map. Let $\mathscr{B}=\{w_\alpha:\alpha\in A\}$ be a basis of $W$; for each $\alpha\in A$, pick $v_\alpha$ such that $f(v_\alpha)=w_\alpha$ and define $g\colon W\to V$ by stipulating that
$$
\text{for each $\alpha\in A$, $g(w_\alpha)=v_\alpha$}
$$
By standard results, $g$ is well defined; moreover $f\circ g$ is the identity on $\mathscr{B}$, so it is the identity on $W$.