# Sweedler notation and String diagrams: coaction on quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, quotient-spaces, coalgebras

Let $(C, \Delta, \epsilon)$ be a coalgebra (in the category $Vect$), and $I \subset C$ a right coideal, i.e. $\Delta (I) \subset I \otimes C$.

Define a counital coaction $\overline \Delta := (x_{(1)} + I) \otimes x_{(2)}$ of $C$ on $C/I$.

1. How would you write down $\overline \Delta$ as a composition of maps?
   In the following way: $(\pi \otimes id_C) \circ \Delta \circ \pi ^{-1} = \overline \Delta$, where $\pi: C \rightarrow C/I$ denotes the canonical projection and $\pi^{-1}$ a right inverse of $\pi$? 
   The map $\pi^{-1}$ might not be linear, so that possibly $\overline \Delta$ is not linear?

EDIT (my own answer): The right inverse is not unique, one has to choose an inverse using the axiom of choice. One can always choose the right inverse to be linear. This is proven here: [Linearity of the right inverse of a surjective linear map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1755166/linearity-of-the-right-inverse-of-a-surjective-linear-map)

2. How would you write down $\overline \Delta$ in a string diagram?
   In the following way? Here the map $\pi^{-1}$ denotes a linear right inverse of $\pi$ which always exists (see above). Hopefully, it is clear what convention in drawing the diagram I am using.
   [image]

Comment: You only want a string diagram for the category Vect?

Comment: @AHusain: Yes, I edited the question, see above.

Comment: Why would you like to write $\bar{\Delta}$ as composition of maps? Its existence and uniqueness follows from the universal property of the quotient. I mean, $\bar{\Delta}$ is the unique linear map such that $\bar{\Delta} \circ \pi = (\pi \otimes id_C) \circ \Delta$. In particular, any $\sigma:C/I \to C$ such that $\pi \circ \sigma = id$ would do the trick and since you are over a field, everything is free and hence $\sigma$ exists..

Comment: @Ender Wiggins: Why do I want to write $\overline \Delta$ as a composition of maps? To write it as a string diagram, in order to get more familiar with Sweedler notation and string diagrams.

Comment: @Ender Wiggins: You are right, thank you. What do you mean by “since you are over a field, everything is free”? Doesn’t the existence of a map $\sigma: C/I \rightarrow C$ such that $\pi \circ \sigma = id$ follow from the surjectivity of $\pi$, i.e. surjectivity implies existence of a right inverse (the proof uses the axiom of choice again)?

Comment: It does and it follows from the AoC, in some sense. Because it follows from AoC that over a field everything is free. But over fields you are already using atomic bombs so you don't need to invoke AoC again. Anyway, the point of my comment is that trying to write $\bar{\Delta}$ as composition of maps "hides" its uniqueness (because $\sigma$ is not unique of course)